# Вызвать событие при выборе ДВУХ из МНОГИХ checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день.

Как в jquery (вероятно) вызвать другое событие только после включения двух из многих checkbox.

Comment: Вызывать событие на каждый выбор, проверяя в нём, что выбрано 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Назначим всем чекбоксам один обработчик, в котором будем проверять количество выбранных:

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
  var checked = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
  if (checked >= 2) {
    console.log(checked + " - call event");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: Забираете мой хлеб :) +1

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ваш ответ описание кода, чтобы пользователям было легче его понять. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Решение работает везде, кроме моего кода:(
@Igor Мои <input type="checkbox"> зашиты в таблицу, это может влиять на выполнение кода?

Comment: Решил проблему просто добавив скрипт в самый конец кода.